# SQL query : Inner join with distinct values

Tags: sql

I have two tables :

Table 1

```
ID | Name          
12   User1          
77   CostCenter1    
78   CostCenter2    
79   CostCenter3    
14   User2
```

Table 2

```
UserID | AssignedCostCenter
12   77       
12   78   
12   79    
14   78
```

1st table collects identities (users, cost centers).
2nd table represents users and their allowed CostCenters.

I would like to achieve the following:
query should returns a single column which have a list of (unique) users who have assigned more then 1 cost center (two and more).

I started with join two tables by:

```
Select Table 1.Name
from  Table 1
inner join Table 1.ID = Table 2.UserID
```

The result is:

```
User1
User1
User1
User2
```

Comment: have you tried `DISTNICT` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "user1" and "user2" because of `inner join` based upon Ids. 
To get the list of users who have been assigned more than 1 cost center (two and more), modify your query as:

```
SELECT Table 1.Name
FROM Table 1
INNER JOIN Table 2 ON Table 1.ID = Table 2.UserID
GROUP BY Table 1.Name
HAVING count(Table 1.name) > 1
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'll have to upgrade sql engine to 2012, becouse there is 2008 R2 and I'm afraid that having and group by wouldn't be available currently

Comment: i think it would work with 2008 as well. Check out the this page at https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3790436/Grouping-with-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Comment: @qba . . . Of course `having` and `group by` are available.  They are fundamentals of the SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

Using `group by` on the `userid` in `table2` allows use of a `having clause` which filters out those who only have 1 cost centre, then the inner join to that result will list the just the names of those who have more than one cost centre.

```
SELECT
    Table1.Name
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        UserID
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY
        UserID
    HAVING COUNT(UserID) > 1
    ) AS t2 ON Table1.ID = t2.UserID
```

Comment: this one works perfectly win 2008 engine. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear on whether table 2 can have duplicates.  So, it might be safer to approach this query as:

```
SELECT t1.Name
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.ID = t2.UserID
GROUP BY t1.Name
HAVING MIN(t2.AssignedCostCenter) <> MAX(t2. AssignedCostCenter);
```